# Writing pages - selecting correct content with PHP/SQL?

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a blog article system and I fill out a form with the content and then submit it to the database, from there I fopen() and fwrite(). I fwrite() the entire page. How do I recall the information? I was going to select the highest ID in the database and +1 that (thus that ID would be the one I'm writing into my fwrite() however that would change with each article. Is there any information I could pass over to the file which would identify the article specifically? Kinda blanking on what I could do to avoid the fwrite()'d page from pulling hte wrong information from the database later on :).

EDit

```
$included = '<?php 
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","codefund","pw removed");
// Check connection
if (!$connection)
{
    echo "Could not connect to the database: " . mysql_error();
}
mysql_select_db("codefund_articles") or die();
$articleID = 

$page="";
require_once($_SERVER[\'DOCUMENT_ROOT\'].\'/includes/beginning.php\');
?>
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
    <?php require_once($_SERVER[\'DOCUMENT_ROOT\'].\'/includes/header.php\');?>

    <div id="main" class="clearfix">
        <?php require_once($_SERVER[\'DOCUMENT_ROOT\'].\'/includes/sidebar.php\'); ?>

        <div id="mainContent">
            <h1></h1>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php require_once($_SERVER[\'DOCUMENT_ROOT\'].\'/includes/footer.php\');?>

</div>
</body>
</html>';
```

Comment: Quite unclear. You want to bind an ID from your database to a file with the corresponding content, but you don't know how to do that ? Try to give an example of a file and the database schema.

Comment: It sounds like your logic is fairly flawed. what do you need frwite/fopen etc. for if it's a databse driven blog system? Also, you don't manually +1 to the ID fields in a database (well, you can), database software usually supports a field type or index/property that tells it a column (ID column usually) always goes up by 1 for each new row.

Comment: Apologies if I'm unclear. Please refer to the original post for my code. All you need to know for now on my database is I have an ArticleID column. I have a submit.php where I submit all the article data. It auto generates an auto increment ArticleID in the database. I need to have a way to specifically grab that one and not choose the wrong one. I originally wanted to look at the highest ID value b ut that would obviously change. So yes I'm unsure of how to choose the correct ID

Comment: how about you add a content column to your database and forget writting to a file?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I have a content column which hosts the content. You are all missing what I'm trying to say. I will be using a sql function to retreive the content. However that is impossible unless I know which row to select AKA which ID to select. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If your ArticleID is auto_incremented as you said, you can use `mysql_insert_id()` to retrieve the ID of the last inserted row.

That way you'll be sure to get the ID of the row you added in you script, and can therefore use that ID and be sure that it will correspond to the article you're 'fwritting' next. (And use it to name your article for example)

There are several examples on mysql_insert_id usage on the PHP manual :
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Clement I had thought about that but imagine I have even 10 articles. Each page will pull the same content if they pull the highest data. Each page will have that same SQL

Comment: @RyanReese No, why ? Your content is in a file, right ? And that file include the ID somehow (title, first line or dunno) I guess ?

Comment: If it included the ID I wouldn't have an issue. The only ID available to me is the one that gets auto incremeneted in database. I made 2 articles and my fwrite() template file now includes that mysql_insert_id and on both pages it returned 0. as i expected. I write the article - submits to database. Then I fwrite the article page into existance. but I have no way of selecting the proper entry in my database!!!!!!!!! My content is written on my website admin.php and from there i submit the form to submit.php and I grab it as $_POST

Comment: If mysql_insert_id returns 0 it means that "the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT value" as said by the doc. You ArcticleID field in your DB is not a real AUTO_INCREMENT value I guess.

Comment: I moved the mysql_insert_id() into the actual submit.php page (I had moved to the blogarticle page I "created" via fwrite and that returnd 0. I moved it to submit.php and it seems to be working. Thanks